# É possível construir um cadastro em HTML puro?

Tags: php, html, html5, xml, xhtml

Preciso criar um cadastro com nome e descrição em HTML, ou PHP, que não faça uso de um banco de dados mas não sei se é possível.

Algo que pudesso guardar os registros em arquivo e também carregá-los de volta ao formulário.

A página conteria:

- Formulário com os campos `Nome` e `Descrição` (campo para 200.000 caracteres no mínimo)
- Grid que listaria os registros, que poderiam ser selecionados para edição
- Botões para salvar, editar, remover e criar novo registro

A idéia é rodar em um computador sem que seja necessário a instalação de um sistema de banco de dados, ou algo parecido. Ele rodaria por conta própria sem depender de outros programas ou instalação, rodando apenas no navegador.

Alguma idéia de como isso pode ser feito?

Comment: É possível. http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/features/storage

Comment: Tem um exemplo em http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/?redirect_from_locale=pt

Comment: Sim, LocalStorage (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), WebSQL (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) e particularmente utilizo HTML5SQl.js (http://html5sql.com/) que é de fácil implementação.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, você pode fazer isso usando HTML e PHP, mas seria necessário a manipulação de arquivos do lado do servidor, note que: É possível, porém não é muito seguro visto que qualquer um com acesso ao servidor poderia acessar os cadastros (A não ser que eles estejam criptografados).

### Vamos lá

Primeiro você precisaria montar um form comum em HTML, creio que você já saiba fazer isso, caso não saiba, você pode dar uma olhada [neste link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

A Action do formulário deverá estar apontando para sua página em PHP, nela você deverá receber **todos** os dados necessários via **POST** ou **GET**.

A estrutura da página PHP deverá ser algo parecido com:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{

 <Criação dos campos>;

}
```

Dentro desta estrutura IF você terá que realizar todo o processo para a criação de um arquivo em um formato XML para a leitura, este arquivo pode estar em qualquer formatação que você desejar, ou seja, você pode criar tags dentro dele de modo que seja mais simples para você ler o mesmo.

Ex:
    
    
      
        Pedro Henrique Correia
        Lorem Ipsum

Então você poderá gravar usando [este tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038535/create-new-xml-file-and-write-data-to-it) ou um destes abaixo:

- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?14165-Read-and-write-XML-with-PHP
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265274/php-create-and-save-a-txt-file-to-root-directory
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php

Você pode dar um nome e um caminho de gravação como preferir e, para ler e buscar os dados que você quer, você pode [ler isto aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp).

*Note que se você quiser ler uma arquivo criptografado, primeiramente você terá de lê-lo como String, e depois usar o simpleXml para transformá-lo em XML*

Se o sistema for utilizar uma grande quantidade de dados, eu aconselho você ir adicionando nodos, ao invés de criar um arquivo para cada usuário ou para cada registro, assim quando o sistema for iniciado ele pode ler todos os documentos em um objeto ou um array de uma unica vez, fazendo com que o processamento seja infinitamente mais rápido.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma legal para resolver seu problema é utilizando o Local Storage do HTML 5, a grosso modo ele é um banco de dados contido no navegador, como se fosse um cookie que não tem data para expiração, isso quer dizer que ao fechar o browser os dados armazenados no Local Storage não são perdidos, é importante salientar que os dados guardados por esse recurso não poderão ser acessados por outros computadores através da rede, funcionará apenas no navegador do cliente que possui e que guardou a aplicação.
O que é necessário para utilizar o Local Storage? conhecimentos em HTML e Javascript, segue um link com um exemplo de utilização do mesmo:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-html5-local-storage-e-json/29045